# R package or function to record filters applied to your tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, r-recipes

Does there exist any R function or packages that records the operations applied to a tibble/data frame?

For example, if I did the following

```
data(iris)
my_table <- iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% filter(Species == 'virginica')
```

I would want the output to be something of the form

```
display_filter_function(my_table)

output:
Step   filter
1       sepal.length > 6
2       Species == 'virginica'
```

I am thinking that this would be something similar to the functionality provided by the recipes package, but not needing to use the step_ family of function

Comment: One challenge here is that the dataset may be `mutated()` in "midstream", to delete old columns and introduce new columns.  So the final result might be meaningless, if the `sepal.length` and `Species` columns no longer exist, or if they have been renamed.

Comment: that makes sense-- so you think that any function that may exist for this must contain all operations (mutates, joins, filters...) in order to be accurate (not just filters)

Comment: This sounds like it could made as an extension to the `tidylog` package, which focuses on recording the *effect* of each step in a dplyr chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a little module for you.  It is a standalone resource and has only one dependency beyond [**`base`**](https://rdrr.io/r/#base) R: namely [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) itself.  **The module is long, so I have put it at the bottom of this post.**  You can find the code itself under the **Module** section, and its usage is demonstrated under the **Usage** section.

This model could theoretically be extended to all **`dplyr`** functions, and to other generic functions as well.  To keep things manageable, I myself have implemented it for [`dplyr::filter()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) alone.

## Background

This module leverages the R concept of [generic methods](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-methods), like [`print()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/print.html) and [`format()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/format.html) and [`mean()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/mean.html) and [`summary()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/summary.html).  Suppose you wish to `print()` a [`data.frame`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/data.frame.html) object. The generic `print()` function...

```r
print
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("print")
#> <bytecode: 0x000002429186e2c8>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

...**does *not* do the work itself**!  Rather, it [*dispatches*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#method-dispatch) to some `print.*()` method, via the line:

```r
UseMethod("print")
```

Now the native `data.frame` class has its own special `print()` method called [`print.data.frame()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/print.dataframe.html).

```r
print.data.frame
#> function (x, ..., digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, max = NULL) 
#> {
#>     n <- length(row.names(x))
#>     ⋮
#>     invisible(x)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000002429186b7e0>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

So when [`UseMethod()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/UseMethod.html) seeks a matching (`"print"`) method, it finds `print.data.frame()` ready and waiting!  It is the `print.data.frame()` function that actually handles the printing for the `data.frame`.

More generally, a generic function like `fn()`...

```r
fn <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("fn")
}
```

can be implemented for a ([S3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3)) class like `cls`, with a function of the form `fn.cls()`:

```r
fn.cls <- function(x, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ...) {
  # ...
}
```

### Note

The `fn.default()` method handles `fn()` for unimplemented classes.  So in the absence of a `print.cls()` function, then `UseMethod()` would dispatch a `cls` object to [`print.default()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/print.default.html):

```r
print.default
#> function (x, digits = NULL, quote = TRUE, na.print = NULL, print.gap = NULL, right = FALSE, max = NULL, width = NULL, useSource = TRUE, ...) 
#> {
#>     args <- pairlist(digits = digits, quote = quote, na.print = na.print, ...
#>     ⋮
#>     .Internal(print.default(x, args, missings))
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000024291917b80>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

## Approach

By defining a custom [S3 class](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3) called `hst_obj` — "historical object" — I override the "generic" behavior of `dplyr::filter()`...

```r
dplyr::filter
#> function (.data, ..., .preserve = FALSE) 
#> {
#>     UseMethod("filter")
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000024292d10b40>
#> <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

...which is **designed to dispatch** via `UseMethod("filter")`.  To that end, I implement the function `filter.hst_obj()`:

```r
filter.hst_obj
#> function (.data, ..., .preserve = FALSE) 
#> {
#>     .update_hst(x = `class<-`(dplyr::filter(.data = un_hst_obj(.data, ...
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000002428f842958>
```

When you call `dplyr::filter()` on a `hst_obj` object, then `filter.hst_obj()` jumps into action!  **Whenever it filters the object, it also *records* the filtration criteria in the special attribute `obj_hst`**, which maintains the "object history".

This history is a [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html)...

```r
# A tibble: m × 4
   step order expr       text            
  <int> <int> <list>     <chr>           
1     1     1 <language> sepal.length > 6
⋮      ⋮     ⋮      ⋮             ⋮
```

...which has four columns:

- **`step`**: The `filter()` step in the workflow.

```r
iris %>%                              # step
  filter(Sepal.Length > 6) %>%        # } 1
  filter(Species == 'virginica') %>%  # } 2
  ...                                 #   ⋮
```

- **`order`**: The criterion *within* the `filter()` step.

```r
     filter(a < 10, b == 3 | c > 5, ...)
#           |----|  |------------|
# order:       1           2        ...
```

- **`expr`**: The actual code ([`language`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.language.html)) for the criterion (`Sepal.Length > 6`), useful for programmatic manipulation of R.
- **`text`**: A textual (`character`) representation of that code (`"Sepal.Length > 6"`), for visual clarity.

## Usage

You'll want to load **`dplyr`** itself, and then [`source()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/source.html) the module (`mod.R`) from (say) your working directory.

```r
# Load the `dplyr` package...
library(dplyr)

# ...along with the `hst_obj` functions from the module:
source("./mod.R")
```

---

#### Warning

The modular function **`filter.hst_obj()` *must* be loaded into the same workspace where you use `dplyr::filter()`**.  Per the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/base/UseMethod.html)

> `UseMethod`...search[es] for methods in two places: in the environment in which the generic function is called, and in the registration data base for the environment in which the generic is defined (typically a namespace). **So methods for a generic function need to be available in the environment of the call to the generic**, or they must be registered.

---

Here is a simple workflow on the [`iris`](https://rdrr.io/r/datasets/iris.html) dataset.

```r
iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 7, Sepal.Width <= 3) %>%
  filter(Petal.Width > 2)
#> Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
#> 2          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
#> 3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#> 4          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Now we transform the dataset into a "historical object" called `iris_hst`, via `as_hst_obj()`.

```r
iris_hst <- as_hst_obj(iris)
```

Per `is_hst_obj()`, it is indeed a historical object.

```r
iris_hst %>% is_hst_obj()
#> TRUE
```

However, its history via `get_hst()` is still blank.

```r
iris_hst %>% get_hst()
#> # A tibble: 0 × 4
#> # … with 4 variables: step <int>, order <int>, expr <list>, text <chr>
```

We now perform the same workflow on the *historical* dataset `iris_hst`...

```r
iris_hst <- iris_hst %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 7, Sepal.Width <= 3) %>%
  filter(Petal.Width > 2)
```

...which yields a consistent output.

```r
iris_hst
#> Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
#> 2          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
#> 3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#> 4          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Crucially, **we can now access the history** via `get_hst()`:

```r
iris_hst %>% get_hst()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    step order expr       text            
#>   <int> <int> <list>     <chr>           
#> 1     1     1 <language> Sepal.Length > 7
#> 2     1     2 <language> Sepal.Width <= 3
#> 3     2     1 <language> Petal.Width > 2
```

We can also "reset" the history via `reset_hst()`, which clears the `tibble` of historical data.

```r
iris_hst <- iris_hst %>% reset_hst()

iris_hst %>% get_hst()
#> # A tibble: 0 × 4
#> # … with 4 variables: step <int>, order <int>, expr <list>, text <chr>
```

Finally, we can revert to an "unhistorical" object via `un_hst_obj()`, which removes the `hst_obj` classification and deletes the `obj_hst` attribute:

```r
iris_unhst <- iris_hst %>% un_hst_obj()

# It is no longer a "historical" object...
iris_unhst %>% is_hst_obj()
#> FALSE

# ...and the history is nonexistent (not merely blank) entirely.
iris_unhst %>% get_hst()
#>
```

## Module

Here is the module.  I recommend saving it locally, as (say) `mod.R` in (say) your working directory.  I also recommend the [**`box`**](https://klmr.me/box) package, which can load such modules painlessly via [`box::use`](https://klmr.me/box/reference/use.html)`(./mod)`.

```r
#########
## API ##
#########

# Test if an object is "historical object" whose filtrations are recorded.
is_hst_obj <- function(x) {
  inherits(x, .HST_OBJ_CLASS)
}


# Treat an object as "historical".
as_hst_obj <- function(x) {
  if (!is_hst_obj(x)) {
    class(x) <- c(.HST_OBJ_CLASS, class(x))
  }
  
  x
}


# Erase the "historicity" of an object.
un_hst_obj <- function(x, hst = TRUE) {
  if (is_hst_obj(x)) {
    org_class <- class(x)
    class(x) <- org_class[org_class != .HST_OBJ_CLASS]
    
    if (isTRUE(hst)) {
      x <- .set_hst(x, hst = NULL)
    }
  }
  
  x
}


# Get the history from a historical object.
get_hst <- function(x) {
  hst <- attr(x, .OBJ_HST_ATTR)
  
  if (is.null(hst)) {
    if (is_hst_obj(x)) {
      .BLANK_OBJ_HST
      # NULL
    } else {
      invisible(NULL)
    }
  } else {
    hst
  }
}


# Reset the history for a historical object.
reset_hst <- function(x) {
  if (is_hst_obj(x)) {
    x <- .set_hst(x, hst = NULL)
  }
  
  x
}



##############
## Dispatch ##
##############

# Dispatch filtration for historical objects.
filter.hst_obj <- evalq(envir = new.env(), {
  # Define the filtration function: `dplyr::filter()`
  fn_expr <- quote(dplyr::filter)
  #                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  #                 UPDATE HERE
  fn <- eval(fn_expr)
  
  # Replicate in our result the signature of that original function.
  arg_syms <- as.list(args(fn))
  arg_syms <- utils::head(arg_syms, n = -1)
  arg_syms <- sapply(names(arg_syms), as.symbol, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
  
  
  # Prepare the elements for the function body...
  obj_sym <- arg_syms[[1]]   # The (1st) argument (.data) for the object...
  cnd_exprs <- arg_syms$...  # ...and dots (...) for filtration condition(s).
  
  # ...including a similar call to the filter with an "ahistorical" object...
  arg_syms[[as.character(obj_sym)]] <- substitute(un_hst_obj(
    obj_sym,
    hst = FALSE
  ))
  fn_call <- as.call(c(list(fn_expr), arg_syms))
  
  sub_list <- list(
    obj = obj_sym,
    cnd = cnd_exprs,
    cll = fn_call
  )
  
  # ...and assemble those elements.
  fn_body <- substitute(env = sub_list, quote({
    .update_hst(
      # Perform the unclassed call and then restore any "historicity"...
      x = `class<-`(cll, class(obj)),
      # ...and then update the history with the filtration criteria.
      exprs = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$cnd
    )
  }))
  
  
  # Pair this body with the header from `dplyr::filter()`...
  fn_body <- eval(fn_body)
  body(fn) <- fn_body
  
  # ...and transfer the resulting function to the calling environment.
  environment(fn) <- parent.frame(n = 2)
  
  
  # Return the resulting function.
  fn
})



#############
## Support ##
#############

# Labels for the object class...
.HST_OBJ_CLASS <- "hst_obj"

# ...and its history attribute.
.OBJ_HST_ATTR <- "obj_hst"

# The default history for an object.
.BLANK_OBJ_HST <- dplyr::tibble(
  step = integer(),
  order = integer(),
  expr = list(),
  text = character()
)


# Set the history for a historical object.
.set_hst <- function(x, hst) {
  attr(x, .OBJ_HST_ATTR) <- hst
  x
}

# Update the history with a list of filtration expressions.
.update_hst <- function(x, exprs) {
  # Augment the history of a "historical" object.
  if (is_hst_obj(x)) {
    # Get the current history.
    hst <- get_hst(x)
    
    # # ...and default if the history is missing.
    # if (is.null(hst)) {
    #   hst <- .BLANK_OBJ_HST
    # }
    
    
    # Augment the history: format the new additions...
    next_cnd <- exprs
    # next_cnd <- sapply(next_cnd, as.expression, simplify = FALSE)
    next_txt <- sapply(next_cnd, deparse, simplify = TRUE)
    next_ord <- seq_along(next_cnd)
    
    if (length(exprs) == 0) {
      next_stp <- integer()
    } else if (nrow(hst) == 0) {
      next_stp <- 1
    } else {
      next_stp <- max(hst$step) + 1
    }
    
    next_hst <- dplyr::tibble(
      step = as.integer(next_stp),
      order = as.integer(next_ord),
      expr = as.list(next_cnd),
      text = as.character(next_txt)
    )
    
    # ...and append them to the existing history.
    hst <- dplyr::bind_rows(hst, next_hst)
    
    
    # Update the history.
    x <- .set_hst(x, hst = hst)
  }
  
  # Return the updated object.
  x
}
```

Comment: Greg this is amazing and works as I would like. Thank you for your thorough explanation :)